# Как использовать Builder, когда нужно изменить поля уже заполенного объекта

Tags: java

У меня есть класс, который имеет Builder. Когда я создаю объект данного класса, то я использую Builder для заполнения полей.

Но иногда мне нужно менять уже существующий объект и Builder уже здесь не работает.

Может что не так делаю, можете мне пояснить как можно применить Builder когда нужно менять поля уже готового объекта

```
public class Produce extends TwoBaseAbstract {

    private String name2;

    private String product;

    public Produce() {
        super();
    }

    private Produce(Builder builder) {
        setId(builder.id);
        setName(builder.name);
        setNum(builder.num);
        setMark(builder.mark);
        setName2(builder.name2);
        setProduct(builder.product);
    }

    public static Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public String getName2() {
        return name2;
    }

    public void setName2(String name2) {
        this.name2 = name2;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        Produce produce = (Produce) o;
        return Objects.equals(name2, produce.name2) &&
                Objects.equals(product, produce.product);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), name2, product);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return super.toString() + "\n" + " - Produce{ " +
                "name2 = '" + name2 + '\'' +
                ", product = '" + product + '\'' +
                " }";
    }


    public static final class Builder {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private Integer num;
        private String mark;
        private String name2;
        private String product;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder id(Long val) {
            id = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder name(String val) {
            name = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder num(Integer val) {
            num = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder mark(String val) {
            mark = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder name2(String val) {
            name2 = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder product(String val) {
            product = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Produce build() {
            return new Produce(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Как я понимаю Builder возвращает новый объект в своей обертке, которая позволяет заполнить поля и вернуть этот объект в точку вызова ?

Поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: `Но иногда мне нужно менять уже существующий объект` у вас ведь судя по конструктору `Produce` уже есть методы-setter'ы для всех полей, что в `Builder` заполняете, почему бы их не вызывать?

Comment: потому что я некоторые поля сделал private, среда разработки предложила,  а когда сохраняю в svn , тогда появляются предупреждения, что можно сделать некоторые поля private. А пример я привел тестовый, у меня сущность из нескольких десятков полей

Comment: `Builder` был создан для удобного создания объектов -- чтобы не создавать конструкторы с кучей аргументов, или чтобы после создания объекта не вызывать кучу его сеттеров. Поэтому, если у вас объект может изменяться после создания сделайте, то уберите у его сеттеров приватность

Comment: Я обычным сеттерами вернул public. Так все работает. То есть Builder предназначен только для заполнения нового объекта  и только?

Answer (score 1):

> То есть Builder предназначен только для заполнения нового объекта и
>   только

Да

---

**Builder** был создан для удобного создания объектов -- чтобы не создавать конструкторы с кучей аргументов, или чтобы после создания объекта не вызывать кучу его сеттеров.

Поэтому, если у вас объект может изменяться после создания сделайте, то уберите у его сеттеров приватность.

**Builder** относится к шаблону проектирования [Строитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)):

> Строитель (англ. Builder) — порождающий шаблон проектирования
>   предоставляет способ создания составного объекта.